# PHP storing db credentials in session

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP, is it alright to store database credentials in $_SESSION? I am looking for a way to avoid including config files every time I need to use config vars.

Comment: This sounds like an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)** to me.

Comment: there's nothing wrong in having a config file included all the time!

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use $_SESSION for this, because it [seems like it would be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9028875/5827005)

Comment: Maybe Jeff haha. Using session vars just seemed easier to me. But maybe not :P

Comment: @ZachAbrams including a config file is really easy. Most config files are near the root of your project, you can include them on any page by doing `include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/path/to/config'`, the path will start from the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sticking with the config file, as it allows changes in real time, if you change the config then this data will change instantly for any users that are online, where sessions would have to be set again every time it's changed. Always including a config may be easier than you think.

You can include a file using a path from your directory root, like this:

```
<?php 
   include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/config.php";
?>
```

Where the path should be from your document root, basically from the root of your project. A lot of the time people keep this file in their root, so if your config file is at `http://example.com/config.php`

using this include will load it from any php file in your project.

```
<?php 
   include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php";
?>
```

> **Also, as Qirel mentioned:**
>
> The config should be stored outside the public folders - only
>   accessible by the server (and not directly in the browser).

Comment: Just a note, `include` isn't a function, so the parenthesis isn't needed. Also the config should be stored *outside* the public folders - only accessible by the server (and not directly in the browser).